# WPF - How to reference element inside Style programmatically

Tags: wpf, reference, element, styles

How can I reference the ItemDecorator element in code?

```
<Style x:Key="DesignerItemStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
          <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            <s:MoveThumb Cursor="SizeAll" Template="{StaticResource MoveThumbTemplate}" />
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
            <s:DesignerItemDecorator x:Name="ItemDecorator"/>
          </Grid>
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
              <Setter TargetName="ItemDecorator" Property="ShowDecorator" Value="True"/>
            </Trigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GetTemplateChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.gettemplatechild.aspx) to the rescue. Refer to this article for the example: [Creating a WPF Custom Control](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/32d63678-2798-465e-ad29-c0b45fb68b78/creating-a-wpf-custom-con.aspx)

Comment: I tried that but I couldn't make it work. Can you give me the exact code?